# getElementsByClassname from selection box

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

If I select option 1 i want to get `categClass1`.
If I select option 2 i want to get `categClass2`.
etc ...

I want to get those in function `addCategory` :

```js
function addCategorySelectBox(i) {

    var  = document.getElementById("newCateg").value;
    var y = document.getElementById('selectCategory');
    var option = document.createElement("option");
//create class name dynamically;
    option.setAttribute('class', "categClass" + i);

    option.value = categoryValue;
    option.text = categoryValue;
    y.add(option);
    var newCategClass = "categClass" + i;
   
    return "categClass" + i;
    
}
function addCategory() {
// ??
var x =document.getElementsByClassName(newCategClass);
    
}
```

```html
    <p>Ονομα Kατηγορίας:
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="new-cat" id="newCateg" />
        </label>
        <input type="button" name="add-c" id="addCateg" value="Προσθήκη" onclick="return addCategorySelectBox(1);addCategory()" />
    </p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <p>Κατηγορία:
        <select id="selectCategory">
            <option>Επιλογή ...</option>
            <option class="categClass1">Εξοδα Κατοικίας</option>
            <option class="categClass2">Εξοδα Εκπαίδευσης</option>
            <option class="categClass3">Εξοδα Ψηχαγωγίας</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Why -2 grades  people ?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because it's a little unclear as to what you want.  Could you expand on the information provided a little to give a bit more context or ideas about where you're having problems in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept is as follows :

1. create a function to handle the behavior you want;
2. set the function from the first article as a handler to the HTML element.

*HTML :*

```
<select id="selectCategory" onchange="getClass(this)">
    <...>
</select>
```

*JavaScript :*

```
function getClass(sel){
   console.log(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].className)
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tr8vfp0s/)

You can also set handler via js methods, without interacting with html :

```
document.querySelector('#selectCategory').onchange = function (){
   console.log(document.querySelector('#selectCategory option:checked').className)
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tr8vfp0s/2/)

There is also an option with using `setAttribute()` method, the only flaw is a hard-coded part `'getClass(this)'`.

```
function getClass(sel){
    console.log(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].className)
}
document.querySelector('#selectCategory').setAttribute('onchange', 'getClass(this)')
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tr8vfp0s/3/)